# How to serve YAML/text files as response using AWS lambda in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, pyyaml

I cannot get the information on how to serve static files as responses in AWS Lambda. I have a YAML file content which needs to be sent as a YAML file(should be downloaded as a file in the browser) when user hits a HTTP GET request. How to configure the lambda function and what changes should we make in the API gateway while creating the request?

Sample Lambda function:

```
import yaml
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    test_url = 'http://www.google.com'

    with open("test.yml") as f:
        list_doc = yaml.load(f)
    # updating a variable in yaml file
    list_doc[0]['vars']['url'] = test_url
    with open("/tmp//return_file.yml", "w") as f:
        yaml.dump(list_doc, f, default_flow_style=False)
    # how to send this return_file.yml as http response?
    # return {
    #     'statusCode': 200,
    #     'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    # }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [enable binary support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) of your REST API for type `*/*` or `application/octet-stream`.

Then in your `lambda_function.py`, you need to return like this

```
    f = yaml.dump(filename, encoding='utf-8')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'},
        'body': f.decode('utf-8')
    }
```